# When I move a control, the client rectangle is duplicated WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, gdi

[image]

I have a Custom Control which allows you to move controls around on the screen. For some reason, whenever I move the control, the ClientRectangle is duplicated. These are two separate rectangles. I have checked that my code is not duplicating any objects, and it doesn't seem to be. It seems the client rectangle sticks in the same location.

In my image, I have drawn around the client rectangle in red to make it obvious.

Whenever I resize the control, both the visible control and the orphaned client rectangle change size together. I can't understand why this is happening.

This is the code to move the control on the screen.

```
protected virtual void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_selectedControl != null && _leftMouseDown)
    {
        if (_resizingControl)
        {
            Point pt = Cursor.Position;
            Point position = GetRelativePosition(_selectedControl);

            // Work out the expected right position and adjust the width so the right 
            // position matches. Do same with Bottom and Height
            int computedRight = _selectedControl.Left + PointToClient(pt).X;
            int increaseWidth = computedRight - _selectedControl.Right;
            _selectedControl.Width += increaseWidth - position.X;

            int computedBottom = _selectedControl.Top + PointToClient(pt).Y;
            int increaseHeight = computedBottom - _selectedControl.Bottom;
            _selectedControl.Height += increaseHeight - position.Y;

            ApplyTransformConstraints(_selectedControl);
        }

        else
        {
            Point pt = Cursor.Position;
            Point newlocation = new Point(PointToClient(pt).X - _offsetOnClientControl.X,
                PointToClient(pt).Y - _offsetOnClientControl.Y);

            _selectedControl.Location = newlocation;
        }

        _selectedControl.Refresh();
        _selectedControl.Invalidate();
    }

    Invalidate();
    Refresh();

    if (ControlFromPoint(e.Location) != null)
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    else
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    if (_resizeRectangle.Contains(e.Location) || _resizingControl)
        Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
}
```

Any ideas of why this would be happening or a potential fix to it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution, but a way to find out the course of a problem: if you `Invalidate()` the complete Custom Control, for instance after a button click, do you still display two ClientRectangles? If this solves the problem, then you should invalidate the rectangle that you want to disappear

Comment: @Harald_Coppoolse Invalidating the rest of the control still causes the client rectangle to be duplicated unfortunately. Had a thought about it myself. I’m thinking perhaps it’s a problem with GDI? I’ve got lots of Forms experience but nowhere near enough to debug those kinds of problems.